# Stable values in vertex shader, unstable in fragment when rendered with webgl

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm working with an unfamiliar scene and trying to render an array of points.

In the vertex shader i have this `if/else` block that resizes every 6th point and the last 3. This works as expected, points render at different sizes and as i navigate the scene they remain consistent.

However, when i run the same `if/else` tests in the fragment shader to color points differently it melts:

[image]

vert block:

```
  gl_PointSize = uPointSize;

  if(int(vIndex) == uTrajectoryCount - 1){
    gl_PointSize = uPointSize * 2.0;
  } 
  else if(int(vIndex) == uTrajectoryCount - 2){
    gl_PointSize = uPointSize * 1.6;
  }
  else if(int(vIndex) == uTrajectoryCount - 3){
    gl_PointSize = uPointSize * 1.3;
  }
  else if( 
    abs(mod(vIndex,6.0)) < 0.01 
  ) {
    gl_PointSize = uPointSize * 2.0;
  }
```

frag block

```
  if(int(vIndex) == uTrajectoryCount - 1){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.);
  } 
  else if(int(vIndex) == uTrajectoryCount - 2){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.,1.,0.,1.);
  }
  else if(int(vIndex) == uTrajectoryCount - 3){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.,0.,1.,1.);
  }
  else if( 
    abs(mod(vIndex,6.0)) < 0.01 
  ) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.,1.,0.,1.);
  }
```

What could i look for that would make this "stable" i expect the bigger points not to flicker and stay yellow, and the last three to be r g b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a rounding issue related to floating point imprecision.Why you construct an *int* from a *float* the value is truncated. Round the value with `floor(vIndex+0.5)` or `round(vIndex)` instead of `int(vIndex)`.

Comment: But what about the mod to 6th, that one involves no int cast? It did stabilize the last 3 to my surprise.

Comment: heh that worked with `floor(vIndex+0.5)`.

Comment: I have other code that i foolishly didn't include thinking that i could make sense out of this answer. Say that im using the varying `vIndex` and this thing happened with precision that i don't understand, but i want to use it for a texture lookup. 
Eg `vec2( (index + 0.5) / 512.0 , 0.5 );` should i `floor(index+0.5)` here as well?